# only top condition is working not others for url rewriting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my htaccess code for url-rewriting.
I have a problem here.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 404error.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ news.php?url=$1

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ social.php?url=$1

</IfModule>
```

here are three pages with different data. When I click for **spcification.php** page data then it will redirect me on same page but if my this code is above from this then it will redirect me to on news.php.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ news.php?url=$1
```

only top condition work not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know you cannot use same rule for multiple conditions like this

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1
```

When first rule matched it stop searching for same condition, instead you have to use

```
RewriteRule ^specification/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ news.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Your original url will look like this `domain.com/news/value`.

Comment: My new code for these three pages is

`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ news.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^social/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ social.php?url=$1`

first one is working proper and also css is working. On others page like news.php and social.php data is coming but css is not working. Link is like like domain.com/news/jdfhbh-jksabfhd-djhfbsv fine but css doesn't work.

Comment: Add `<base href="/" >` in `<head>` section of your news and social page.

Comment: I added this code also but still not working.

This is my website but still working offline
[theMobilesApp](http://www.themobilesapp.com)

Comment: Try using by giving full domain name <base href="http://www.themobilesapp.com/" >

Comment: This is **Awesome** Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Can you help me on this url writing Question.?
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506906/htaccess-showing-error-when-i-try-to-open-page**