# htaccess showing error when I try to open page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two page and I'm trying to make good looking url for these links.
First link :-

**http://www.themobilesapp.com/tags.php?tag=Android**

for to convert this url into this url.

**http://www.themobilesapp.com/tag/Android**

for this i write this code.

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ tags.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Second link :-

**http://www.themobilesapp.com/phones.php?title=Apple**

for to convert this url into this url.

**http://www.themobilesapp.com/brand/Android**

for this i write this code.

```
RewriteRule ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ phones.php?title=$1 [L]
```

But on both pages one same error is coming.
This error is coming on my page
**Internal Server Error**

and my whole htaccess file code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
Options -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

ErrorDocument 404 404error.php

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^news/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ news.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^social/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ social.php?url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^tag/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ tags.php?tag=$1  [L]

RewriteRule ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ phones.php?title=$1  [L]

</IfModule>
```

All RewriteRule rules are working except below two.

Comment: Does the error persist if you add the `[L]` flag after the rules that don't have it?

Comment: Yup, it is coming after adding `[L]`

This error is coming.

**Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check for spellings and make sure file exist, try to use below simplified rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#after above rewrite cond use below rewrite for each page in below manner
RewriteRule ^tags/([\w-]+)$ tags.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This code is not working and I use this for this `RewriteRule ^tag/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)? tags.php?tag=$1 [L]` and `RewriteRule ^brand/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)? phones.php?title=$1 [L]` and these are working fine after using  `<base href="http://www.localhost/themobilesapp/" >`  and this is only possible due to your help. So, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: for more help. You can read this question-answer page with full url-rewrite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42502040/only-top-condition-is-working-not-others-for-url-rewriting

Comment: bro. help me on this. Please read my question carefully. I edit little bit there and you will understand and also comment there for further conversation. Help me to solve my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001226/500-internal-server-error-is-coming-when-im-redirecting-my-normal-page-to-amp-p